# Multiple Over writes using FileWriter in Java

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

Im trying to read N different CSV files containing stock price data. I want to extract one particular column from each file and showcase those columns in a single CSV file.

The issue is the combined file contains only the written data from the first file I give as input i.e. that data is not being overwritten in the iteration of my loop.

Can someone help? Or suggest a new method?

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {

    int filecount=0;
    System.out.println("Enter Number of Files");
    Scanner stream =new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     filecount= Integer.parseInt(stream.next());

    File file2 = new File("Combined_Sym.csv");
    FileWriter fwriter= new FileWriter("Combined_Sym.csv",true);
    PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(fwriter);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<filecount;i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter File name "+i);
    String fileName =stream.next();
    File file = new File(fileName);

    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    Scanner inputStream2= new Scanner(file2);

    if(!inputStream2.hasNext()){
    outputFile.println(fileName);
    }
    else
    {       String header=inputStream2.next();
    System.out.println(header+","+fileName);
        outputFile.println(header+","+fileName);
    }

    while(inputStream.hasNext())
    {
    String data= inputStream.next();
    String[] values = new String[8];
    values = data.split(",");
    String sym=values[7];

    if(!inputStream2.hasNext())
    outputFile.println(sym);
    else
    {
        String data2= inputStream2.next();
    outputFile.println(data2+","+sym);
    System.out.println(data2+","+sym);
    }

    }

    inputStream.close();
    inputStream2.close();
    outputFile.close();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing :

```
for(i=0;i<filecount;i++)
{
System.out.println("Enter File name "+i);
String fileName =stream.next();
File file = new File(fileName);
```

to

```
File file;
for(i=0;i<filecount;i++)
{
System.out.println("Enter File name "+i);
String fileName =stream.next();
file = new File(fileName);
```

Comment: No this wont work. The problem is with the FileWriter. Since I created a File "Combined_Sym.csv" in the JAVA code so I could read from it , and simultaneously I am writing to a file of the same name using FileWriter. Some overlap is happening and in the second iteration of my loop the FileWriter doesnt write into the file as it is already filled ( hence there is an overwriting issue, so I need some help to understand how I can over write the file )